# Is it possible to trigger the workflow manually?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Is that possible to trigger the workflow manually?

Say for example that I don't want to trigger the workflow when I save and close my component, but I want to update the component multiple times and, after I feel I am OK, I want to trigger the workflow attached for component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to understand a few things about Tridion workflow. It is not designed or intended to be a *process workflow*, it's an approval workflow.

When changes are done to items that require workflow, workflow starts (item is locked). When you're done with the changes, you finish your activity and move on along the workflow process.

From the sound of it, you're probably working for an organization where workflow drives content publishing, while Tridion was designed from the ground up to *not* require workflow to publish to a website, workflow is simply for organizations requiring additional validation steps (some would say it's because they can't trust the editors, but that's a different story, which is easier to solve with permissions than workflow, but I digress).

Anyway, the good news for you is that the Workflow engine is being re-designed as we speak, and the next release will bring a lot of new *process-oriented* concepts into our workflow engine. But currently, what you want to do is not possible.

Answer (score 5):

Like Jeremy said it's not possible (yet), but it would also spoil the whole idea of Workflow that is - you can't have unapproved content checked in. In your case, you can edit component as many times as you want. No matter if you just save it or save and close. It will pass on to the next activity in workflow as soon as you will report "i'm done" - that is finish your activity.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. Workflow can only be triggered on the Save of an item. For the situation you mention you simply need to finish the initial activity at the point you are satisfied with the content.